# Input onchange javascript function call not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari

I have an html canvas that shows a preview of an image when the image is selected in an input. This works in Chrome, but I can't seem to get it to work in Safari. Specifically - in Safari - the `onchange="previewFile()"` does not seem to call the previewFile function.

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="0" height="0"></canvas>

<h2>Upload a photo </h2>
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // setup the canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

    // grab the photo and display in canvas
    var photo = new Image();
    function previewFile() {
        var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        var reader  = new FileReader(); 

        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            photo.src = reader.result;
            canvas.height = photo.height;
            canvas.width = photo.width;
            ctx.drawImage(photo,0,0);
        }, false);

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }      
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is certainly due to the fact that you are not waiting for the image has loaded before you try to draw it on the canvas.

Even wen the source is a dataURI, the loading of the image is asynchronous, so you need to wrap your drawing operations in the image's `onload` event.

```
var photo = new Image();
photo.onload = function(){
  canvas.height = photo.height;
  ...
  }
...
reader.onload = function(){
  // this will eventually trigger the image's onload event
  photo.src = this.result;
  }
```

But if all you need is to draw your image on the canvas, don't even use a FileReader, actually, the `readAsDataURL()` method should trigger a `I'm doing something wrong` error in your brain. Almost all you can do with a dataURI version of a Blob, you can also do it with the Blob itself, without computing it nor polluting the browser's memory.

For example, to display an image for user input, you can use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` method.

```js
// setup the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// grab the photo and display in canvas
var photo = new Image();
// drawing operations should be in the mage's load event
photo.onload = function() {
  // if you don't need to display this image elsewhere
  URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);

  canvas.height = this.height;
  canvas.width = this.width;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
}
photo.onerror = function(e) {
  console.warn('file format not recognised as a supported image');
}
file_input.onchange = function() {
  // prefer 'this' over DOM selection
  var file = this.files[0];
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  photo.src = url;
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="0" height="0"></canvas>

<h2>Upload a photo </h2>
<input type="file" id="file_input">
<br>
```

And for those who need to send this file to their server, use a `FormData` to send directly the Blob. If you really need a dataURI version, then convert it server-side.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed the problem and you taught me a thing or two!